# How delete firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I use this code below and run well in Firebase RealTime Database:

```
const onDelete = (id) => {
  if (
    window.confirm("Are you sure that you wanted to delete the contact ?")
  ) {
    Db.child(`contacts/${id}`).remove((err) => {
      if (err) {
        alert(err);
      } else {
        alert("Contact Deleted Successfully");
        console.timeStamp(id);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Now I create another database in Firebase Firestore but cannot delete.

```
const onDelete = (id) => {
  if (window.confirm("Are you sure that you wanted to delete contact ?")) {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("contacts")
      .doc(`${id}`)
      .delete()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: "but cannot delete" Why not? Is there an error message?

Comment: No error messages, just not performed the delete. I checked and when I put the doc.id like fGh6pQekhMj0AdFXccxx runs well. For Firebase real time accepts just the id like (0,1,2,3...n) but Firestore not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that last comment. In both databases you need to specify the exact path you want to delete.

Comment: Yes, this delete is inside one contact table, each line have one delete link. Because this I need specify the id to delete just this right line (document). In Firebase Realtime I don´t need specify the doc.id, I just use the id and run well. Not happen in the same way in Firestore, I need specify the doc.id to delete document.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in the databases here: in both cases you have to specify the full path to the data to be deleted.

If you can somehow specify line numbers for the Realtime Database, most likely you've used those line numbers as keys in your database. And if you can't do the same on Firestore, it's likely you didn't use the line numbers  as document IDs there. If that is indeed the case, you'll need to either maintain a mapping from line numbers to document IDs, or use the line numbers for the document IDs in Firestore too.

Answer (score 0):

```
const onDelete = async (id) => {
    if (
      window.confirm("Are you sure that you wanted to delete the contact ?")
    ) {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("contacts")
        .get()
        .then(async (querySnapshot) => {
          await deleteDoc(doc(db, "contacts", querySnapshot.docs[id].id));
          alert("Contact Deleted Successfully");
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Please properly format and explain your code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).